# Crosstabs with Qualitative and Quantitative Variables in R

Tags: r

I have only seen R crosstabs with two qualitative (categorical) variables so far. I would like to see a working example of a crosstab table using R for one qualitative and one quantitative variable. For example, if I want to find the relationship between Quality Rating (Good, Fair, Poor) and Price ($10 - $19, $20 - $29, $30 - $39), how can I achieve this using R? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The way you have presented price in categories, you could treat it as categorical for a crosstabs summary.

Comment: Thanks Sal. But I have a dataset containing two columns - Price and Quality Rating. Price is Quantitative. I am new to R and am trying to see how I can group the $ amounts and create a crosstab. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely not the smoothest option, but one that will work is

```
    # Construct dataframe
    quality <- rep(c("Good", "Fair", "Poor"),4)
    price <- c(10,11,12,13,14,17,19,125,25,22,21,22)
    price.cat <- rep(NA, length(price))
    data <- data.frame(quality, price, price.cat)

    # Define new factor variable for certain price categories
    for (i in 1:length(price.cat)){

    # Category 0$-19$
    if (data[i,"price"]<=19){
    data[i, "price.cat"] <- "0-19"}

    # Category 20$-29$
    if (data[i,"price"]>=20 & data[i,"price"]<=29){
    data[i, "price.cat"] <- "20-29"}

    # Category 30$-125$
    if (data[i,"price"]>=30 & data[i,"price"]<=125){
    data[i, "price.cat"] <- "30-125"}
    }

    # Crosstabulate
    table(data$quality, data$price.cat)
```

By adjusting the code you can set up your own categories. The output will look like this:

[image]

Is this what you want?

Comment: So here the trick is to create a new column full of NAs, which are then recoded into different price categories. These new categories are then crosstabulated against your quality rating variable.

Comment: Lion - thanks for the detailed code. Yes. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for showing the output.

Comment: Nice to hear that. Don't forget to mark the answer as correct. Then other people will find help easier!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to summarize numeric data across groups.

There are many ways to do this in R, but my favorite is a function in the FSA package.

Other examples can be found at the following link: [R Handbook: Descriptive Statistics](http://rcompanion.org/handbook/C_02.html).

```
if(!require(FSA)){install.packages("FSA")}

Price = c(10,11,12,13,14,17,19,125,25,22,21,22)
Quality = rep(c("Good", "Fair", "Poor"),4)

Quality = factor(Quality, 
                 order = c("Poor", "Good", "Fair"))

Data = data.frame(Price, Quality)

library(FSA)

Summarize(Price ~ Quality, 
          data=Data)
```